# How (and when) to move AlertDialog in Android to a new position on the screen?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I need to move Android's AlertDialog to a location on screen which does not obscure some activity widgets. I have two problems actually:

1. I can set dialog window position using LayoutParams and wnd.setAttributes() with LEFT|TOP gravity before the call to dlg.show(). However I need to measure the dialog size in order to calculate the dialog position. **Can I measure the AlertDialog size before it is shown?** All ways to measure the dialog size that I know require retrieving of the view inside the window but just calling wnd.getDecorView() causes the subsequent dlg.show() to throw an exception "Request window feature must be called before setting the content". Thus I cannot measure the AlertDialog size before the show() is called, can I?
2. Once the dialog is lay out I can get its size. For example I can use wnd.setCallback() and then in onContentChanged() I can add a OnGlobalLayoutListener to the decor view in order to get notification onGlobalLayout(). In that notification I can move the dialog using two methods:
   A. either using LayoutParams and wnd.setAttributes()
   B. or using LayoutParams and mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(wnd.getDecorView(), lp);
   The dialog is moved, but... It is then moved back to the original position. I can see it on the display moving to the new position and then moving back to the original position. WTF?!?!?

   I tried to postDelayed() the dialog moving and if the delay is > 300ms it seems to work. But would it work on all Android devices? I guess not... So the question is **when is it appropriate to move the AlertDialog to a new position?**

Does anybody know a better way to calculate alert dialog size and move it at a new location on screen?

Thanks!

Comment: `when is it appropriate to move the AlertDialog to a new position?` never

Comment: can you elaborate on why?

Comment: What widgets do you need visible? By their very nature, dialogs are intended to block user interaction with your application until they take an appropriate action with the dialog. You also shouldn't be moving them around because your app would be the only app on the user's phone that doesn't use the default behavior for dialogs (centered on screen).

Comment: widgets which might help users take decision which button to press in the AlertDialog. And I have other reasons which I am not allowed to discuss.

Comment: To get height of views that have not yet been drawn i use viewtreeobserver

Comment: Thanks, Rico, that is what I did. See the second note - the dialog is moved at the new location and then it is moved back...

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.alertDialogMove;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int x;
    int y;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        x=0;
        y=0;
        adb();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void adb(){
        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ad.setTitle("Um, I am an alert dialog made by rico");
        ad.setMessage("To change my position hit the button move me");
        ad.setPositiveButton("Click to move me",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                int Min=0;
                int Max=200;
                x=Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
                y=Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
                dialog.cancel();
                adb();
            }


          });
        ad.setNegativeButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog aD = ad.create();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = aD.getWindow().getAttributes();

         wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
         wmlp.x = x;
         wmlp.y = y;
         aD.show();
    }
}
```

You can easily shift like above, by dismissing and remaking it at new position, I don't know how to get its height ;(

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  
1. This is not moving but closing and recreating the dialog. As my application  consists of different modules I will not be able to recreate the dialog created by another module.  
2. onClick() is not appropriate to be used because I would like to move the dialog as soon as it is shown.

Comment: And the click was just for representation, to dismiss the dialog u can use alertdialog.dismiss(); you dont have to wait for user interaction.